# adding default strings to textarea by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to add "@username" to my textarea. I think I'm missing something fundamental so I'd appreciate if you could help me find out what it is.

js function:

```
function dropdown() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropup() {
 document.getElementById("myDropup").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
 if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
 var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
};

function truncate(id,id2,id3) {
  var element=document.getElementById(id);
  var element2=document.getElementById(id2);
  var element3=document.getElementById(id3);
  element.style.display = "none";
  element2.style.display = "block";
  element3.style.display = "none";
};

function insertText(text){
  var elem = document.getElementById("id_content")
  elem.value += text; 

};
```

html:

```
<div>
  <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{EntryForm}}
        <div class=text-bottom>
            <ul class=navul2>
                <li><button type="button" class=text-edit-but onmousedown="event.preventDefault()"><img class=link
                            src="{% static 'icons\link.png' %}" alt='link'></button></li>
                <li><button onclick="insertText('@username')" type="button" class=text-edit-but onmousedown="event.preventDefault()"><img class=link
                            src="{% static 'icons\yazar.png' %}" alt='link'></button></li>
                <li><button type="button" class=text-edit-but onmousedown="event.preventDefault()"><img class=link
                            src="{% static 'icons\lines.png' %}" alt='link'></button></li>
                <li><button type="submit" class=text-edit-but1 onmousedown="event.preventDefault()"><img class=link
                            src="{% static 'icons\share.png' %}" alt='link'></button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

textarea:

    <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="10000" class="entry-content" placeholder="sen ne diyorsun?" onfocus="window.scrollBy(0,233)" spellcheck="false" required="" id="id_content"></textarea>
```

onmousedown="preventDefault" is not the problem as I tried to press it by turning it into a submit button and it worked. It's there because I don't want the button to get the focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

textarea is input so use value

```js
 function insertText(text){
   var elem = document.getElementById("id_content")
   elem.value += text; 
         
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="insertText('@username')" type="button" class=text-edit-but onmousedown="event.preventDefault()"><img class=link src="{% static 'icons\yazar.png' %}" alt='link'></button>

<textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="10000" class="entry-content" placeholder="sen ne diyorsun?" onfocus="window.scrollBy(0,233)" spellcheck="false" required="" id="id_content"></textarea>
```

Comment: it was one of my options but it didn't work, thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Can't you add @username to textarea? or u can but can't u submit it ?

Comment: I just can't add it. By the way all the other functions in my page are working fine and are on the same js file.

Comment: So you should share your whole html code. In snippet it is working. So your problem is different from your sharing

Comment: I just added the whole js file by editing it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did u try to put textarea in form tag. It is out of form element. This can cause problem.

Comment: Io I didn't as it's genereted inside form tag by django itself, didn't think it could be the problem.

Comment: To understand write one textarea out of form and try to add it , if it works your problem is form tag

Comment: Well I did as you said, placed a new textarea, also changed the id in getelementbyid in accordance with the new textarea but the problem goes on.

Comment: Turns out your last suggestion worked but the css file on local server didn't update, thanks a lot my friend!